# PHP MongoDB Nested Document Search

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a nested Document which have some language dependent content and I want to search if content have data for specific language and query should return me content else false.

I tried this query option

```
$data = $collection->findOne(array('original'=>'What is this', 'translation.language'=>'english') );
```

I am expecting this result:

```
{
       "language": "english",
       "quote": "What is this"
}
```

but above query return both language content. Can anyone please share some code also regarding saving and updating data using PHP

My collection:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("56a8844bc56760810e483815"),
   "language": "english",
   "original_key": "What is this",
   "translation": [
     {
       "language": "english",
       "quote": "What is this"
    },
     {
       "language": "spanish",
       "quote": "What is this Spanish"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`positional $`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)** operator in the projection document of the `findOne()` method when you only need one particular array element in selected documents:

```
// search criteria for nested array
$query = array(
    'original' => 'What is this', 
    'translation.language' => 'english'
);

// projection (fields to include)
$projection =  array('_id' => false, 'translation.$' => true);

$result = $collection->findOne($query, $projection);
$data = $result->translation;
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked :). Can you also share some code to insert new language data to existing collection ex. inserting Arabic language sub-document into exiting record?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use mongodb's [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/).

This may work. Not tested.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind :translation},
    {$project: {original_key:true,language:true, quote:true}},
    {$match:{original_key:"What is this", language:"english"}}
]);
```